# Validar si selecciono un valor en los checkboxs

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Cuando selecciono uno o varios de los posibles `checkbox`, me muestra el mensaje o los mensajes que tengo en el `PHP`, pero si no selecciono ninguno de los posibles `checkbox` me sale el siguiente error:
"Notice: Undefined index: TipoM in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tarea_02\accion.php on line 11"

**La linea 11**

```
$TipoM=$_POST["TipoM"];
```

¿Como puedo solucionar ese error?

Adjunto fragmentos de mis codigos:

**Formulario HTML**

```
Elige tipo de mensaje: <br><br>   
        <select multiple name="TipoM[]">    
        <option value="Top_Secret" checked>Alto secreto</option>    
        <option value="Reserved">Secreto</option>    
        <option value="Indifferent">Indiferente su difusión</option>    
        <option value="Obligatory">Difusion obligatoria</option> 
        </select><br><br>
```

**CODIGO PHP**

```
   function Mostrar_TipoMensaje ($TipoM)
    {

            for ($i=0;$i<count($TipoM);$i++)    
            {     

                       if(($TipoM[$i])==("Top_Secret"))
                       echo 'TOP SECRET<br>';
                       else
                           echo("");

                       if(($TipoM[$i])==("Reserved"))
                       echo 'RESERVED<br>';
                      else
                           echo("");

                       if(($TipoM[$i])==("Indifferent"))
                       echo 'INDIFFERENT<br>';
                       else
                           echo("");

                       if(($TipoM[$i])==("Obligatory"))
                       echo 'OBLIGATORY<br>';
                       else
                           echo("");
             }


}
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow la linea 11 para mi es la definicion de la variable en el PHP, es decir para mi la linea 11 es tal que así: `$TipoM=$_POST["TipoM"];`

Comment: @JackNavaRow y puedo hacer algo para que en caso de que no se seleccione ninguna te muestre un mensaje diciendote que se debe seleccionar al menos una de las posibilidades en lugar del error?

Comment: No entiendo, podrías explicarlo? @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes hacer lo siguiente:

Si viene por post esa key la guardas en $TipoM, sino guardas null

```
$TipoM=isset($_POST["TipoM"])?$_POST["TipoM"]:null;
```

Por otro lado en tu funcion verificas que si la variable por parametros no es null la recorres.

```
function Mostrar_TipoMensaje ($TipoM)
{
    if($TipoM){

        for ($i=0;$i<count($TipoM);$i++)    
        {     

            if($TipoM[$i]=="Top_Secret")
                echo 'TOP SECRET<br>';
            else
               echo("");

            if($TipoM[$i]=="Reserved")
                echo 'RESERVED<br>';
            else
               echo("");

            if($TipoM[$i]=="Indifferent")
                echo 'INDIFFERENT<br>';
            else
               echo("");

            if($TipoM[$i]=="Obligatory")
                echo 'OBLIGATORY<br>';
            else
                echo("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, otra vez eres la salvación del problema jajaja.

Answer (score 0):

El error arrojado es cuando no seleccionas un valor los checkboxs no envian el valor al formulario.
Debes tener algun tipo de validacion como:`!$_POST["TipoM"]`, preguntar si no envio nada.

**Ejemplo**

```
if(!$_POST["TipoM"]) {
    echo "debes seleccionar algo";
}else{
    //tu codigo
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @JackNavaRow